# Setting ADFS Login To Be Persistent Across Browser Sessions

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, adfs

We’ve got a CRM 2011 implementation using IFD which in turn means is uses claims based identity and ADFS.
I’m struggling to determine how I can keep my user logged in across multiple browser sessions.

I’m not an ADFS expert; I know enough to watch the How-2 video for CRM IFD and click through the wizards. Usually I'd back myself to Google something like this in no time but I've had no luck to date.

Can anyone provide some guidance as to how I might configure some sort of persistence of login in this setup? i.e. for the user to remain logged in and able to return directly to CRM even when they close their browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the TokenLifetime. Refer:

[CRM 2011 ADFS and TokenLifetime](http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2011/08/crm-2011-adfs-and-tokenlifetime.html)

Comment: We have this set to 24hr already. It doesn't persist over the close of the browser session though.

Comment: That's related to the SAML token's lifetime, though, isn't it? Chris is more concerned with the fact that the browser cookie itself that wraps the token is set to expire immediately upon closing the browser (session cookie).

Answer (score 0):

It is hardcoded to be a session cookie in `Microsoft.Crm.Authentication.CrmSessionAuthenticationManager, Microsoft.Crm.Authentication`

You would need to decompile the class, change the code and configure CRM to use your new module in the web.config